# How to get inner html from an html page and display it on an angular component?

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml

I have the following page "../posts/postxx.html", and I would like to programmatically take the innerHTML of the page (i.e. `<h1>My Blog Post</>`... etc.) and insert it in a div in an angular component?  I've been trying like this on

```js
ngOnIinit {
  this.fileUrl = `../posts/${this.id}/${this.id}.component.html`;
  fetch(this.fileUrl)
    .then((r) => {
      r.text().then((d) => {
        let blog = d
        console.log(blog);
      })
    })
},
}
```

but I'm getting cannot Get error: `<pre>Cannot GET /posts/...!`

Comment: `ngOnIinit` ???

Comment: Have you defined the posts directory as an asset in angular.json? You'll need to do that to access the files directly instead of relying on angular's routing

Comment: Thanks for your reply,@ShamPooSham, yes I tried that, added a folder posts in angular.json/assets and tried to use an iframe [src]="../assets/posts", but it did not work.

Comment: @AlexCocan You were probably close but got the reference wrong. Can you update your question with how you set that up and tag me again when you're done?

Comment: Thanks @ShamPooSham, however I had to give up on this solution as I found an acceptable workaround. With regards to the src, it was the predictive VS path, hence I doubt would be have been wrong. I will leave this open as I'm still interested to see a solution to this, hence if you have time please post an example/demo on stackblitz.io.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just put an iframe in your html page :

```
<iframe [src]="fileUrl"></iframe>
```

Comment: Sorry , tried that but does not work, does not read the file url, is only showing the iframe! Thanks for trying though, appreciate it!